# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm making a javascript metro app and have some code like this:

```
    <script>
       document.writeln(foo());//this line is trouble
    </script>
```

and when I tried to run, it gave me a rather long error:

> Unhandled exception at line 20, column 9 in ms-appx://a375ffac-3b69-475a-bd53-ee3c1ccf4c4e/default.html
>
> 0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content.
>   A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously
>   modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the
>   innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this
>   exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or
>   explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as
>   createElement.  For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

How can I get around this?

Comment: [Why is document.write considered a 'bad practice'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Why `document.writeln()` and not a real DOM manipulation method?

Comment: It says it in the exception, "use the toStaticHTML method."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regarding to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ie/cc848922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I would try :

```
document.writeln(window.toStaticHTML(foo()));
```

Answer (score 13):

Windows 8 restricts the content you can set through innerHTML and Writeln, because it's considered unsafe...

The correct way to add content is:

```
// The untrusted data contains unsafe dynamic content
var unTrustedData = "<img src='http://www.contoso.com/logo.jpg' on-click='calltoUnsafeCode();'/>";

// Safe dynamic content can be added to the DOM without introducing errors
var safeData = window.toStaticHTML(unTrustedData);

// The content of the data is now 
// "<img src='http://www.contoso.com/logo.jpg'/>" 
// and is safe to add because it was filtered
document.write(safeData);
```

If your code has some javascript, you can use this function (But microsoft dont recomend it):

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.innerHTML = '<div style="color:' + textColor + '">example</div>';
});
```

See at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767331.aspx

For your case:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
    document.writeln(foo());
});
```

Note that you should only do this if you understand your content is safe; if you don't, I would recommend using the `toStaticHTML` method.

Comment: Yep. I was having trouble getting jsviews and jquery data binding to work.  It was throwing this same error.  I just had to wrap my template/link code block in execUnsafeLocalFunction and it all ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 store apps have a restriction on placing dynamic content inside innerHTML attribute. To fix this you need to include winstore-jscompat.js file from following location in your page as first reference. Please see [this link to know more about winstore-jscompat](https://github.com/Microsoft/winstore-jscompat).

This file is not required on Windows 10.