# Cordova jQuery WP 8 - Blocking Excedpion

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, runtime-error

I would like to deploy an app on WP8 with cordova.

I created the enviroment using `cordova platform add windows`but when I tried to deploy my app on the emulator I got this error:

`0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, ...`

In this answer [Windows 8 Phonegap Application JQuery Mobile Security Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454810/windows-8-phonegap-application-jquery-mobile-security-exception) I've read that:

`WinJS security model won't allow the JQuery dom manipulation when you create elements from strings e.g. using the .html() method.`

But the only method I'm using from jQuery is toggleClass();

I read the issue was fixed in jQuery 2.0, but I'm using 2.1.1...

Any suggestion on how to fix?