# Windows Phone 8.1 appx crash adding cordova.js (Phonegap Build)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app using Phonegap Build.
The problem is the .appx generates crashes 1-2 seconds after it opens. This crash occurs if I add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in my **index.html** file. Of course, I need it to initialize all cordova plugins. I tested it on real device.

This is my config.xml: https://github.com/widonwaker/test/blob/master/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem; in order to debug I tried building and running the app in Visual Studio 2015 and found it was related to this problem: [JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471362/javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-add-dynamic-content)

Solutions include using a specific compatible version of jQuery, using Windows 8 compatibility shim JS library, or skipping the Windows 8 platform entirely (Windows 10 doesn't have the same restrictions).